# Cannot Find Module 'ytdl-core' (Discord bot)

Tags: node.js

After adding 'ytdl-core' to node_module in files. I tried to use it for a discord bot by requiring (`const ytd1 = require('ytd1-core');`) but it errors and does this:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ytd1-core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\David\Documents\Discord Bot\discordbot.js:14:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

I tried looking up fixes, in my terminal I used `npm install ytdl-core`, `yarn add ytdl-core` and nothing happened. The folder does exist with no pop up error.

The bot can find the discord.js file in the node_module but not ytdl-core. I don't know if it didn't install right, if I have to do something manually, or make it a global file.

Comment: If you look closely you have "ytd**1**", not "ytd**l**"

Answer (score 1):

As @Antony mentioned, I think you've made a typo error. There is no library called `ytd1-core`. Update your require with:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `ytdl` package with `npm i ytdl-core`.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `const ytd1 = require('ytd1-core')` but that package doesn't exists. You need to install the package called 'ytdl-core'. Then you need to require the package with `const ytd1 = require('ytdl-core')`